# TextView selector not working for state_focused

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am working in a project with hardware keyboards on Android devices, so things appearing focusable are an integral part.
Right now one of my clickable `TextView`'s `Selector`is not reacting to `state_focused`, only to `state_selected`and `state_pressed`.

Here is the xml for the TextView:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/text_padding"
        android:onClick="@{viewModel::onShelfClicked}">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/Details_Head_ImageView"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_regalplatz_clean" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/Clickable_Text"
            tools:text="155-07-00-6, 1145-07-00-3" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

The text style:

```
<style name="Clickable_Text">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/selector_clickable_text</item>
    <item name="android:lines">1</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
</style>
```

And, of course, my selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/accent_color_dark_selected" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/accent_color_dark_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/accent_color_dark_selected" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/accent_color_dark" />
</selector>
```

I've already tried making the `TextView` itself focusable, clickable, taking the selector out of the style and putting it directly on the `View` but everything to no avail. No matter what I try, the color only changes when pressing(both with touchscreen or hardware keyboard) but not navigating with a hardware keyboard.

My `targetSdkVersion` is 26 and the `minSdkVersion` is 21.

Comment: just add "android:clickble=true" and "android:focusable=true" to the TextView property

Comment: Both were already added, but to no avail.

Comment: implement onClick() and assign listener to textview

Comment: I've tried making the `onClick()` be activated from the TextView itself, nothing changed. And the clicking is not the problem, but making the selector notice it is being focused.
It can be focused, but the text color doesn't change on focus(using arrow navigation or hardware keyboard). It does change onClick though.

Comment: may i know where did u put selector file?

Comment: On the style and the `textColor` attribute.

Comment: I mean you have to put selector file in res->color

Comment: Really? Okay, I will try that. If it work, can you also write as an answer so I can chose as solution(and you'll gain your well deserved Karma).

Comment: @RajeshKushvaha, I changed it, but putting the file on res->color didn't fix the problem. The text still shows as unfocused using a keypad to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

Add this piece of code in your Activity

```
  TextView txtView; 
     txtView= findVieById(R.id.idOfYourTextView)
```

//after txtView is selected.

```
 txtView.setSelected(true);
    imageView.setSelected(false);
```

Hope this works

Comment: and when u select image you same do same for image
imageView.setSelected(true);
txtView.setSelected(false);